# How to recover the "Open Notebook.onetoc2" file?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

This file probably instantiates all OneNote sections of a notebook. In case this file is lost, the sections become stand-alone and cannot be opened as a notebook.

How can the *"Open Notebook.onetoc2"* file be recovered?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing required is to browse the notebook directory and create a new empty file (e.g. via file browser of the OS) with the name *"Open Notebook.onetoc2"*.

This is a possible path for a notebook named *Notebook1*:

```
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\OneNote Notebooks\Notebook1\
```

When the *"Open Notebook.onetoc2"* is double clicked or opened via *"File > Open"*, all sections and pages under the *Notebook1* directory will be opened as a notebook.